# Nodejs get directory of `required` module

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Is it possible to determine the directory where `required` scripts come from?

My ultimate goal is to...

```
// return the directory where `mysql` module is found
var mysqldir = requiredir('mysql')
if(fs.existsSync(mysqldir+"/README.md")){
  console.log(fs.readFileSync(mysqldir+"/README.md").toString())
}
```

So I can have a handy reference for all these modules, and hopefully people in the enlightened future, will include module docs/cheatsheets intended to be accessed in this manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`required.resolve(...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve) may be what you're looking for:

```
function requiredir(id) {
    return path.dirname(require.resolve(id));
}
```

Though, this will follow the [`main`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#main) setting:

```
> requiredir('grunt')
.../node_modules/grunt/lib/
```

(***Update***: Documentation for the API isn't available anymore, so its use likely isn't supported.) Another option may be to use `npm`'s `view`, though this is limited to registered packages:

```
npm.load({}, function (err) {
    npm.commands.view(['mysql', 'readme'], true, function (err, readme) {
        console.log(readme);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I am really not the first person to want to do this..!

Comment: can you be more precise on how to run function `npm`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Well, it appears the npm's API isn't documented anymore, so it's probably not recommended to try it now. – In the past, you would install `npm` as a dependency of your own project, then `require('npm')` to invoke its `commands` programmatically.

Comment: and btw, `path.dirname(require.resolve(id));` doesn't solve the issue either, since the JS file used by `require()` might not be stored directly in the root of `path_to/node_modules/module`. Any ideas how to get that `path_to/node_modules/module` programmatically in nodejs?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira You could ask `npm` for the [`root`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root) directory, likely with [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html). That'll give you `path_to/node_modules`, at least, which you can [join](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) the module name to. – Or, with `cwd` set to `path.dirname(require.resolve(id))`, you can ask `npm` for the [`prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix).

Comment: I found another solution. Kindly check! Thanks anyway

Comment: btw, I think `npm root` won't always work cause you may have local or global modules

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira If you're just gathering general information about installed modules, you can still include `-g` or `--global` in `npm root`'s arguments with `child_process` functions. If you're doing much more than that (anything with `require`, etc.), then the module [shouldn't be installed globally anyways](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine the absolute path of a module you can use `require.resolve('module')`

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve

You can extract the folder path by a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to know programmatically, the module main directory which nodejs is using, this works

```
require.resolve('module_name').replace(/(.*node_modules.)(.*?)(\/)(.*)/, `$1$2`)
```

## Example

For example, if you want to know where is the module main directory of  module `jquery` which you're using in your nodejs code, the first part

```
require.resolve('jquery')
```

returns (in my case)

```
/home/jfolpf/autocosts/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

Pay attention that `jquery.js` is not stored in the module main directory; nonetheless

```
require.resolve('jquery').replace(/(.*node_modules.)(.*?)(\/)(.*)/, `$1$2`)
```

returns

```
/home/jfolpf/autocosts/node_modules/jquery
```

This takes into account that to resolve a module's path, node always seeks recursively for the folder named `node_modules`, as can be seen in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).